# jquery - float section change height size

Tags: jquery, html

I created page with 2 sides. on the right side i have float section with bootstrap panel that i can drag to the right side sections.

well, the problem is that the right side section does not  get the full page height (from the search  area until the page footer.

I would like that the HEIGHT of the floating section (on the right side) will always be the max height it can be (between the search section and footer), BUT ALSO - the float section may contain lots of panels so it have to had scroll inside it...

I will truly appreciate your help

CSS

```
#res-wrap {max-height: 500px;  overflow-y: auto;    position: fixed;  }
.change-div-canvas {top: -30px; }
```

the current JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var topMargin = 10 - $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 370) {
        $("#res-wrap").addClass("change-div-canvas");   // removed the . from class
        $("#res-wrap").css("margin-top", "90px"); ;     // change margin from top for close infoWindow button
    } else {
        $("#res-wrap").removeClass("change-div-canvas");  // removed the . from class
        $("#res-wrap").css("margin-top", topMargin+"px"); ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css:

```
#res-wrap
{    
    margin-top: 90px;
    height: calc(100% - 75px);
    max-height: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that